# How do I install Image::Magick on mac os x?

Tags: macos, perl, imagemagick

I've attempted installing with brew:

```
brew install imagemagick
```

The installation seems to have completed successfully. However, when attempting to:

```
use Image::Magick;
```

I get the following error message:

```
Can't locate Image/Magick.pm in @INC
```

I don't know much about the perl system on a mac, or where brew might have installed Image::Magick (I'm told it should have installed the perl libraries as part of the imagemagick install).

Comment: I guess you need to install the Perl bindings as well as ImageMagick itself. Not a Perl or a Homebrew user, but I would guess searching for `perl-imagemagick` or `perl-magick` in Homebrew.

Comment: I had to change all references in Makefile.PL from /usr/local to /opt/local, then run perl Makefile.PL, then make, then sudo make install.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

AFAIK `homebrew` version of ImageMagick doesn't contain perl-magick. You should install it from the sources:

- go to http://www.imagemagick.org/download/perl/
- download http://www.imagemagick.org/download/perl/PerlMagick-6.85.0.tar.gz
- open Terminal.app
- cd ~/Downloads
- tar xvzf PerlMagick-6.85.0.tar.gz
- cd PerlMagick-6.85
- perl Makefile.PL
- make
- make test
- make install (or sudo make install)

All the above is guessing - I'm using [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org). MacPorts has two ports: `ImageMagick` for the basic ImageMagick and `p5-perlmagick` for the perl bindings.

Comment: New for 2021: I had to download the version 7 tar file, not version 6. This way, the perlmagick version matches the version 7 version of imagemagick that homebrew now gives you.

Answer (score 0):

On PerlMagick-6.89-1 there are 2 Errors and "make test" with

```
t/filter.t ........ Failed 1/58 subtests
```

and

```
t/mpeg/read.t ..... Failed 2/2 subtests
```

Fix first see

http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=29759

Second

the problem is

https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=102482

see code

t/mpeg/read.t there is a checksum problem

Testcode:

```
20 testRead( 'input.m2v',
21   'd0d08bbb6ea2f9d5d76bc134a4785f3ab25d6b03d66c64bc43b6b2a9174582d7' );
22 
23 #
24 # Motion Picture Experts Group file interchange format
25 #
26 ++$test;
27 testRead( 'input.mpg',
28   'bbffb8cfbd98a111f7ff625fbc2cf49485d92640de702a2e76c0852ead39c6f1' );
```

I think it's no serious problem or a very local.

Therefore in 99.9% off all cases a

```
sudo make install
```

is no problem.

Hopefully next time come a fix from PerlMagick Team.

Answer (score 0):

If someone have difficulties on apple silicon M3 installing Image::Magick. This is what I have done:

1. brew install imagemagick
2. go to http://www.imagemagick.org/download/perl/
3. download http://www.imagemagick.org/download/perl/PerlMagick-7.1.1.tar.gz
4. open Terminal.app
5. cd ~/Downloads
6. tar xvzf PerlMagick-7.1.1.tar.gz
7. cd PerlMagick-7.1.1
8. edit Makefile.PL and change /usr/local to /opt/homebrew

   ```
    # defaults for LIBS & INC & CCFLAGS params that we later pass to 

    Writemakefile
    my $INC_magick = '-I/opt/homebrew/include/ImageMagick-7 -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=1 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16 -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I"' . $Config{'usrinc'} . '/ImageMagick-7"';
    my $LIBS_magick = '-L/opt/homebrew/lib -lMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI -lm -L' . $Config{'archlib'} . '/CORE';
    my $CCFLAGS_magick = "$Config{'ccflags'} -I/usr/include/freetype2 -g -O2 -Wall -pthread -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=1 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16";
    my $LDFLAGS_magick   = "-L/opt/homebrew/lib -lMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI $Config{'ldflags'} ";
    my $LDDLFLAGS_magick = "-L/opt/homebrew/lib -lMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI $Config{'lddlflags'} ";
   ```

   ......

   ```
   'INSTALLBIN' => '/opt/homebrew/bin',
   ```

   ......

   ```
     $inherited =~ s:MAP_LINKCMD\s.*\s*\$\(CC\):MAP_LINKCMD   = \$(PERLMAINCC) -L/opt/homebrew/lib: ;
   ```
9. perl Makefile.PL
10. make
11. make test
12. make install (or sudo make install)

That is how it started working to me.